# Swift Multi Touch for two nodes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

This is how I made my nodes to move when you tap on the left and the right side of the screen but how can I make them separate when one finger in on the left side and the other on the right side ?

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let location = (touches.first)?.location(in: self.view) 
        if (location?.x)! < (self.view?.bounds.size.width)!/2 {
            player1.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: 0 + player1.size.width / 2, duration: 0.1))
            player2.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: 0 + player1.size.width + player2.size.width / 2, duration: 0.1)) 
        } else {
            player1.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: self.frame.width - player1.size.width - player2.size.width / 2, duration: 0.1))
            player2.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: self.frame.width - player1.size.width / 2, duration: 0.1))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

To enable the multiple touch on your game , you should use : `view.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true`. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622519-ismultipletouchenabled) you can find the API references

Then, if you present your scene from a **SKS** file, usually the `anchorPoint` setted is `(0.5,0.5)` so to work with my example below be sure to add this line in your `GameViewController`:

```
scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero
```

before the line `view.presentScene(scene)` to have your `anchorPoint` setted to 0 for your current scene.

You should also think to "protect" your action from multiple calls especially when you launch these actions from the touch event delegate methods. This can be possible with `action(forKey:` where you check if an action is running or not.

I have made a more detailed example to show you how it can be possible to obtain the multitouch for your actions in Sprite-kit:

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene {
    private var player1 : SKSpriteNode!
    private var player2 : SKSpriteNode!
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.player1 = SKSpriteNode.init(color: .red, size: CGSize(width:50,height:50))
        self.player2 = SKSpriteNode.init(color: .yellow, size: CGSize(width:50,height:50))
        addChild(player1)
        addChild(player2)
        self.player1.position=CGPoint(x:self.frame.width/2,y:(self.frame.height/2)+100)
        self.player2.position=CGPoint(x:self.frame.width/2,y:(self.frame.height/2)-100)
        if let view = self.view {
            view.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
        }
    }
    func rightActions() {
        if (player1.action(forKey: "right") == nil) {
            player1.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: 0 + player1.size.width / 2, duration: 0.1),withKey:"right")
        }
        if (player2.action(forKey: "right") == nil) {
            player2.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: 0 + player1.size.width + player2.size.width / 2, duration: 0.1),withKey:"right")
        }
    }
    func leftActions() {
        if (player1.action(forKey: "left") == nil) {
            player1.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: self.frame.width - player1.size.width - player2.size.width / 2, duration:0.1) ,withKey:"left")
        }
        if (player2.action(forKey: "left") == nil) {
            player2.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: self.frame.width - player1.size.width / 2, duration: 0.1),withKey:"left")
        }
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches {
            let touch = t as UITouch
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            let touchedNode = self.atPoint(location)
            let tapCount = touch.tapCount
            print("tapCount: \(tapCount) - touchedNode:\(touchedNode) - location:\(location)")
            location.x < (self.size.width/2) ? rightActions() : leftActions()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want the two nodes to separate when I hold the left and the right side of the screen the first do to player1.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: 0 + player1.size.width / 2, duration: 0.1),withKey:"right") and the other one player2.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: self.frame.width - player1.size.width / 2, duration: 0.1),withKey:"left") ..... sorry i'm new to coding and I can get it to work :(